# Javascript and PHP resolution

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have a problem.

I have an application which write a maximum of 1000 jpg files into a folder located in my web server.

I have to create a player which will read in order these files.
There are 4 buttom, the first is to skip to the last image, the second to the previous image, the third to skip to the next image and the fourth to the first image.
The folder in which images are stored is always changing, oldest are deleted and replaced with new images which come every second.

The code that I posted works. The only problem is that images are not fresh.
If new images come you cannot see them.

I would like to know if I should use a system which reload every time images (I would do it using AJAX) or it is ok in the form that I made it.

Sorry for my very bad English.
Thank you.

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="Javascript">

var indice;
arr = new Array();

function setarray(set_arr)
{
arr = set_arr;
chiamata(0);
}


function chiamata(tipo) 
{
var immagine = document.getElementById('snap');



if (tipo==0)
{
indice = arr.length-1;

}else if (tipo==1)
{
indice = indice-1;

}else if (tipo==2)
{
indice = indice+1;

}else if (tipo==3)
{

indice = 0;

}

if (indice==arr.length-1)
{
document.getElementById("next").disabled = true;
document.getElementById("before").disabled = false;
}else if (indice==0)
{ 
document.getElementById("before").disabled = true; 
document.getElementById("next").disabled = false;
}else
{
document.getElementById("before").disabled = false; 
document.getElementById("next").disabled = false;
}


immagine.src='/images/' + arr[window.indice] +'?rand=' + Math.random();

}

</script>


<?php

exec('ls /var/www/images/ -rt',$arr_images);
$js_array = json_encode($arr_images);

echo "</head>";
echo "<body onload='setarray($js_array);'>";

?>

<form>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td colspan="4"><img id="snap" src="" width="450" height="360"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><button type="button" onclick="chiamata(0)"> << </button></td>
<td><button type="button" id="before" onclick="chiamata(1)"> > </button></td>
<td><button type="button" id="next" onclick="chiamata(2)"> < </button></td>
<td><button type="button" onclick="chiamata(3)"> >> </button></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

<br>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Changing the `src` attribute of an `img` is enough to make it reload the new image. I believe you have other logic/syntax problems in your code that preventing your code to execute correctly.

Comment: Your PHP code executes **ONCE**, when the page is first generated. After that, the output of the PHP becomes a static part of the page. You'd need to use an AJAX call to poll the server periodically to fetch updated file lists. Plus. tis no need to use a function call to set your array. PHP is executing BEFORe the js engine can ever possibly beginning running.  `var arr=<?php echo json_encode($array); ?>;` is all that's required.

Comment: yes i know that it is executed once but i asked because i would like to know if the form in which i made it was correctly and if there were other alternatives. I will change the code in the form that you posted. I will try to use AJAX but i have to check if i need it. thank you